# How to host assets locally under different hostname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, asset-pipeline, assets

I would like to test my assets from multiple hostnames ex: `http://assets1.somehost.dev, http://assets2.somehost.dev`

My assets configs from `development.rb`

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets%d.somehost.com"
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = false
```

So I would like to setup `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets%d.somehost.dev"`

To test that locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your hosts file (I *think* rails only uses four assets hosts by default):

```
127.0.0.1 http://assets1.somehost.dev http://assets2.somehost.dev http://assets3.somehost.dev http://assets4.somehost.dev
```

Wikipedia has a list of [where to find your hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) based on your platform.